# How to make my app work off line as gmail app on android?

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to android application development. 
I want to make an app for android that list some public information and schedules. so it need to access Restful web services hosted on my server. and once the data is loaded user must also view that on off line. what is the best way to make it possible.

Comment: You should store it on your device. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html as a reference.

Comment: save the data into a database http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very brief overview and you'll probably have a bit of reading to do to be able to implement this, the steps are:

- Create an SQLite database to store all data in.
- Implement a `ContentProvider` which provides CRUD access to the database.
- Add an account authenticator and add an account (can be a dummy account if you don't actually use accounts with your application but it's required for the next step, see http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-authenticator.html).
- Create a `SyncAdapter` to keep the database in sync with the web service.

Your UI should be displaying data from the database rather than calling the web service. There are various ways you can trigger a sync e.g. manually by the user or automatically when data changes. You can use observers to update the UI when data changes too.